# Painting a 10x10 grid with 3 colours

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

Can you paint a 10x10 grid with 3 colours such that it doesn't contain any rectangles whose corners are all the same colour? Rectangles must be 2x2 or greater and parallel to the grid's sides. Computers are allowed :)

A similar question about 2 colours is here: [Painting a 4x6 grid with 2 colours](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89329/painting-a-4x6-grid-with-2-colours)

Good luck!

Comment: Is there a clever way to accomplish this task? "Computers are allowed" makes it seem like the question is intended to be solved by brute-force search, rather than any creativity.

Comment: There is likely a clever method given the combinatorial feel of the problem.  If such a method exists, computers ought not to be allowed.

Comment: @Deusovi good question. Even a brute force search program will struggle to find this due to the large search pace, but there are clever algorithms that can solve this. However, there could still be a way that a human can solve this and it will be interesting to see if anyone can do it. By the way, the 4x6 problem I linked to can be done by hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution (not mine):

> [image: 10x10 solution]
>  
> Source: *Rectangle Free Coloring of Grids*, https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.3750 page 28
>  
> The authors of that paper found the solution by placing one color manually and letting a computer program figure out the other two colors.

Comment: Indeed this is the paper that inspired me to look into this problem. Originally they posted a challenge for the first person to find a solution for 4 colors on a 17x17. It turns out that even 18x18 is possible!

Answer (score 2):

**Partial:**

> By the pigeonhole principle, every row and every column contains at least four squares of the same colour. 
>
>  Let us look at this particular colour for each column : this gives a list of $10$ colours. By the pigeonhole principle, at least four of these colours are the same.
>  In an attempt to prove that it's impossible: **in a $10\times 4$ grid, can you place four yellow dots per column in such a way that no four dots are the corners of a rectangle?**
>  It turns out you can place four yellow dots per column in up to five columns while satisfying this condition:
>   [image]
>   If a solution exists, it will have to include a $4\times 10$ subconfiguration of the above, or similar.

Comment: rot13(Vs lbh pna rahzrengr nyy gur cbffvoyr 10k4 fbyhgvbaf, gura sbe nal bar bs gurz gb or va gur yrsgzbfg 4 pbyhzaf, vg'f evtugzbfg 3 pbyhzaf zhfg zngpu gur yrsgzbfg 3 pbyhzaf bs nabgure 10k4 fbyhgvba. Fvzvyneyl, vg'f evtugzbfg 2 pbyhzaf zhfg zngpu gur yrsgzbfg 2 pbyhzaf bs nabgure 10k4 fbyhgvba. Naq vgf evtugzbfg pbyhza zhfg zngpu gur yrsgzbfg pbyhza bs nabgure 10k4 fbyhgvba. Guvf vf orpnhfr jungrire pbyhzaf 5-7 ner, nal 4-jvqgu fhofrpgvba *zhfg* or bar bs gur 10k4 fbyhgvbaf.)

Comment: @hdsdv Not sure I understand: ROT13(gur cvtrbaubyr cevapvcyr qbrf abg nyybj lbh gb fnl fbzrguvat nobhg rnpu naq rirel 4k 10 fhopbasvthengvba).

Comment: Lrf, ohg vs jr pna rahzrengr *nyy* 10k4 fbyhgvbaf, gura nal 4 pbyhzaf bs gur pbzcyrgrq tevq zhfg or bar bs gubfr 10k4 fbyhgvbaf.

Comment: @hdsdv well, sure, but this is clearly not doable by hand, which was my intended purpose.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I just almost made 10x10 by hand, without one in corner.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier i see - i didn't know how many compliant 10x4 grids there were. if it's just a handful of permutations, it should be tractable. But if not I see why it isn't doable by hand.

Answer (score 2):

**Partial** - I don't think one can solve it by hand. Closest one I could find, but missing 3x3 (in 12x12, so "maximum" is 12x9 or 9x12):

> `232311123123`
>  `313122123312`
>  `121233123231`
>  `113232312123`
>  `221313312312`
>  `332121312231`
>  `321123231123`
>  `213312231231`
>  `132231231312`
>  `211221333`
>  `322332111`
>  `133113222`

So, is there a solution? I tried to switch rows and columns, but that leads nowhere.

Comment: Yes a solution exists :)