# Painting a grid with 3 colours such that there are no right-angled triangles of one colour

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

What is the largest rectangular NxM grid (by area) that can be painted with 3 colours, such that no three cells of the same colour form a right-angled triangle. **N and M must be 4 or greater.** We only consider right-angled triangles whose legs are parallel to the grid's edges. For example the following is not allowed:

```
x.....x
.......
x......
```

while the following is allowed

```
...x...
.......
x.....x
```

Here is a similar question: [Painting a 10x10 grid with 3 colours](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89332/painting-a-10x10-grid-with-3-colours)

Good luck!

Comment: admins can you please close this question. It doesn't work.

Comment: You can hit the delete button yourself, if you think the puzzle isn't worth solving.

Comment: Delete doesn't work, because it already has answers.

Answer (score 1):

---

Previous answer, valid before alteration to question.

The maximum area is

> trivially infinite

if one

> simply creates a rectangle three units high and any number of units across (giving it an arbitrarily large area) and fills the first row with red, the second with blue, and the third with yellow.

Note that

> any three-in-a-row of the same colour does not count as a triangle (refer to the [valid solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89332/painting-a-10x10-grid-with-3-colours/89353#89353) of the linked question, which contains many such occurrences).

Comment: You can actually make the rectangle three times as wide. rot13(Bar ebj bs rnpu pbybhe.)

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Indeed, I guess the score is now rot13(gevcyr vasvavgl.)

Comment: Although correct, but not the answer I was looking for. Sorry. I modified the question to make sure that the grid cannot be a single row. Also note that the linked question talks about non-monocoloured rectangles, rather than right-angled triangles.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Then refer to Jaap's suggestion three comments above this one. I will edit my answer as such.

Comment: Ah good point. Changed it to be at least 4 units high and wide.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I think it is also pretty easy to show 4x4 is not possible.

Comment: Argh. I think this whole question is pointless now. I will delete it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Out of interest, did you have a solution in mind before asking?

Comment: No. I thought there would be an interesting solution, but didn't think it through properly. My bad.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky No problem :)