# No four cells forming a rectangle

Tags: mathematics, geometry, combinatorics

You are given a 5x5 square grid with 25 cells. Can you paint 12 cells, such that no 4 painted cells form the corners of a rectangle with sides parallel to the edges of the grid? Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
OXXXX
XXOOO
XOXOO
XOOXO
XOOOX
```

This extends to any $n \times n$ grid, on which you can paint $3(n - 1)$ cells.

Comment: You got it! We can actually do better than $3n-3$ in general. See https://oeis.org/A072567

Comment: Thanks for the link. I knew the projective plane interpretation since very long ago. There are some more interesting results in the linked page.

Answer (score 1):

Same method as for [this previous similar question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/93792/5373):

- > Put labels $A, B, C, D, E$ along the top for each column, then label the rows by certain *subsets* of the set $\{A, B, C, D, E\}$.
- > 5 rows, so 5 different subsets.
- > 12 painted cells, so the sizes of all subsets sum to 12.
- > No rectangles, so no pair of subsets has two elements in common.

How can we do this? For example,

> $\{A,B\}$, $\{A,C\}$, $\{A,D\}$, $\{A,E\}$, $\{B,C,D,E\}$, which gives
>
>  [image]

Comment: I only see 11 painted cells in your picture, and the question asks for 12. I think painting R1C5 would give you a legal twelfth.

Comment: @bobble Oops. My list of sets was right, but somehow I clicked the wrong cells in the picture when making the diagonal. Fixed.